# Is there a setting in VS 2010 that will allow it to recover open files after a project file changes?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

If I have 10 files open and I amend my `csproj` file (for example: add a <kbd>space</kbd>) visual studio complains:

```
The project "XYZ" has been modified outside the environment. 

Press Reload to load the updated project from disk.
Press Ignore to ignore the external changes. The change will be used the next time you open the project.
```

Now, I really want to **reload** cause there are important changes, but I do **not** want Visual Studio to close all my open files, instead I would like it to refresh the ones that still exist and close the missing ones.

Is there any way to get that kind of functionality?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, I wrote an extension to fix this problem in VS10 and VS11: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6705affd-ca37-4445-9693-f3d680c92f38

Enjoy.

Comment: That's a nice extension! It would be even nicer if the modification stack would be saved, so you can undo stuff even after a reload.

Comment: It would be nice if it could integrate with power tools extension's pin tab function!

Answer (score 11):

As this functionality is not built it, I wrote the following macro:

```
Public Sub ReloadProject()
    Dim oldFiles As List(Of String)
    oldFiles = New List(Of String)

    Dim projName = DTE.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.ContainingProject.Name

    For iDoc = DTE.Documents.Count To 1 Step -1
        Dim name = (DTE.Documents.Item(iDoc).FullName)
        oldFiles.Add(name)
        DTE.Documents.Item(iDoc).Close(vsSaveChanges.vsSaveChangesPrompt)
    Next

    Dim projPath As String = DTE.Solution.Properties.Item("Name").Value.ToString() & "\" & projName

    Dim solutionExplorer As Window = DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer)
    solutionExplorer.Activate()

    Dim solutionHierarchy As UIHierarchy = solutionExplorer.Object
    Dim obj As Object = solutionHierarchy.GetItem(projPath)
    obj.Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect)

    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Project.UnloadProject")
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Project.ReloadProject")

    oldFiles.Reverse()
    For Each file In oldFiles
        Dim item = DTE.Solution.FindProjectItem(file)
        If Not item Is Nothing Then
            item.Open()
            item.Document.Activate()
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

When I get the annoying window telling me to reload, I ignore it. And then run this macro after to reload.

Comment: Why didn't you tell me about this in our team chat? DON'T YOU LOVE ME?

Comment: @Jarrod, I'm trying to keep all my competitive advantages, I just can't keep up with you otherwise :)

Answer (score 0):

Since macros are unavailable in Visual Studio 2013, you need an add-in to run macros.  Visual Commander (available in the Gallery) seems to do the trick.  I adjusted Sam Saffron's macro to work in VS 2013 via Visual Commander.

**Edit Feb 2015:** I've also improved it to remember the line number and column of the active document and to log any errors to the Visual Studio macro output window.

Latest version here:  https://gist.github.com/nycdotnet/947025d922fa2af87d03

```
'===============================================================================
' This macro originally written by Sam Saffron, adapted for Visual Studio 2013
'  by Steve Ognibene.  Run in Visual Studio with a macro launcher such as the
'  Visual Commander extension.
' Latest version will be here: https://gist.github.com/nycdotnet/947025d922fa2af87d03
' Original Stack Overflow thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783648/is-there-a-setting-in-vs-2010-that-will-allow-it-to-recover-open-files-after-a-p/28130299#28130299
'===============================================================================
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell
Imports VisualCommanderExt
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class C
    Implements ICommand

    Private DTE as DTE2

    Sub Run(InboundDTE As DTE2, package As Package) Implements ICommand.Run
        Me.DTE = InboundDTE
        ReloadProject(DTE)
    End Sub

    Public Sub ReloadProject(DTE As DTE2)
        Try

            Dim oldFiles As New List(Of String)
            Dim iDoc As Object

            If DTE.ActiveDocument Is Nothing Then
                WriteOutput("You must have a document open to reload a project with this macro.")
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Dim projName = DTE.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.ContainingProject.Name

            Dim activeDocFullName = DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName
            Dim objSel As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
            Dim objActive As VirtualPoint = objSel.ActivePoint
            Dim intOriginallyActiveRowNumber As Integer = objActive.Line
            Dim intOriginallyActiveColumnNumber As Integer = objActive.LineCharOffset

            For iDoc = DTE.Documents.Count To 1 Step -1
                Dim name = (DTE.Documents.Item(iDoc).FullName)
                oldFiles.Add(name)
                DTE.Documents.Item(iDoc).Close(vsSaveChanges.vsSaveChangesPrompt)
            Next

            Dim projPath As String = DTE.Solution.Properties.Item("Name").Value.ToString() & "\" & projName

            Dim solutionExplorer As Window = DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer)
            solutionExplorer.Activate()

            Dim solutionHierarchy As UIHierarchy = solutionExplorer.Object
            Dim obj As Object = solutionHierarchy.GetItem(projPath)
            obj.Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect)

            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Project.UnloadProject")
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Project.ReloadProject")

            oldFiles.Reverse()

            're-open all previously open files
            For Each file As Object In oldFiles
                Dim item = DTE.Solution.FindProjectItem(file)
                If Not item Is Nothing Then
                    item.Open()
                    item.Document.Activate()
                End If
            Next

            'reactivate previously active file
            For Each file As Object In oldFiles
                If file = activeDocFullName Then
                    Dim item = DTE.Solution.FindProjectItem(file)
                    If Not item Is Nothing Then
                        item.Document.Activate()
                        Dim ts as TextSelection = item.Document.Selection
                        ts.MoveToLineAndOffset(intOriginallyActiveRowNumber,intOriginallyActiveColumnNumber,false)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Catch Ex as Exception
            WriteOutput("Exception: " & ex.Message & System.Environment.NewLine & ex.StackTrace)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Function GetMacroOutputPane() As OutputWindowPane
        Dim ow As OutputWindow = _
            DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindOutput).Object()

        Dim outputPane As OutputWindowPane

        Try
            outputPane = ow.OutputWindowPanes.Item("Macros")
        Catch ex As Exception
            outputPane = ow.OutputWindowPanes.Add("Macros")
        End Try

        Return outputPane
    End Function

    Private Sub WriteOutput(ByVal s As String)
        Dim buffer = New System.Text.StringBuilder

        buffer.Append(Date.Now.ToLongTimeString())
        buffer.Append(" ")
        buffer.Append(s)
        buffer.Append(System.Environment.NewLine)

        Dim output As String = buffer.ToString()
        Dim outputPane As OutputWindowPane = GetMacroOutputPane()

        outputPane.OutputString(output)
    End Sub

End Class
```