# How can I reload a visual studio project thru a nuget powershell script

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, nuget, envdte

In Solution Explorer 'DependentUpon' project items are normally disabled as children of the other item (ex. web.config / web.Debug.config). 
The problem I have is when items are dynamically added via nuget/powershell at package install, Solution Explorer doesn't reload the project so the items don't show as dependent. Manually closing and reopening the solution or unload/reload the project fix the issue.
I'd like to automate the Project Reload as part of the install.ps1 powershell script but when I do this I get 'Project Unloaded' errors and nuget rolls back the install. I think this is because the only way I know how to get the Reload context menu is to unload the project first.

I'm looking for the object that gets invoked behind this call. I think if I could execute directly, I wouldn't have to Unload the project first.

```
$dte.ExecuteCommand("Project.ReloadProject")
```

And here is the full code to unload/reload the project in Solution Explorer

```
# Reload a project thru dte/SolutionExplorer Window 
# using Unload and Reload Context Menus.

$project = Get-Project
$shortpath = $dte.Solution.Properties.Item("Name").Value + "\" + $project.Name

#following GUID = Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer
#magic 1 = vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect
$dte.Windows.Item("{3AE79031-E1BC-11D0-8F78-00A0C9110057}").Activate()
$dte.ActiveWindow.Object.GetItem($shortpath).Select(1)
$dte.ExecuteCommand("Project.UnloadProject")
$dte.ExecuteCommand("Project.ReloadProject")
```

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution to this? I'm having the same issues where changes to the project file haven't triggered a project reload after the nuget install or update and I'm left requiring the developer to reload themselves! I'm so surprised this isn't handled automatically by VS especially given the nuget package is updating the project through the VS project object.

Comment: And here I am after 8 minutes posting my final solution (facepalm!) I'm simply 'touching' the project file to reload the project with the following in the Install.ps1:

    $(get-item $project.FullName).lastwritetime=get-date

Comment: Phil, I haven't looked at since I posted the question, but if you have a solution, please post as an answer vs. a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question answered here:
[Is there a setting in VS 2010 that will allow it to recover open files after a project file changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783648/is-there-a-setting-in-vs-2010-that-will-allow-it-to-recover-open-files-after-a-p)
However, it doesn't indicate that reload can be called without first calling unload and it doesn't provide a mechanism for calling directly w/o going thru dte.executecommand.

Answer (score 3):

I've got around this issue by 'touching' the project file and therefore triggering Visual Studio to prompt the user to reload the modified project after the package manager has closed. So my Install.ps1 file looks like this:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

# if there isn't a project file, there is nothing to do
if (!$project) { return }

# Do some stuff here

$project.Save()

# Touch the file to force a project reload
$(get-item $project.FullName).lastwritetime=get-date
```