# Unload all projects in solution

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012

Based off of [How can I reload a visual studio project thru a nuget powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292577/how-can-i-reload-a-visual-studio-project-thru-a-nuget-powershell-script)

I'm thinking powershell is the way to go about this but the package manager console seems to want to just return text if I start a line with `{`

so here's the script I'm trying to get it to run:

```
{ $dte.Windows.Item("{3AE79031-E1BC-11D0-8F78-00A0C9110057}").Activate() 
$dte.Solution | ForEach-Object { $dte.ActiveWindow.Object.GetItem($_.name).Select(1)
$dte.ExecuteCommand("Project.UnloadProject")}
}
```

but when wrapped into a `{` code `}` it just returns the text as a command block

How can I use powershell to unload all projects across the entire solution and solution folders? I'm not very good with powershell, but surely there is a way to do this.

Comment: You have to put the call operation "&" before you scriptblock for it to be invoked: & { code }

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$dte.ExecuteCommand("ProjectandSolutionContextMenus.Solution.UnloadProjects")
$dte.ExecuteCommand("ProjectandSolutionContextMenus.Solution.ReloadProjects")
```

That does the job. You may wish to call `$dte.ExecuteCommand("File.SaveAll")` beforehand.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Exception calling "ExecuteCommand" with "1" argument(s): "Command "ProjectandSolutionContextMenus.Solution.UnloadProjects" is not valid."
At line:1 char:20
+ $dte.ExecuteCommand <<<< ("ProjectandSolutionContextMenus.Solution.UnloadProjects")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation