# Reload C# project during NuGet install without prompt

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget, csproj

I am altering the csproj file directly via xml manipulations and then call the `Save()` method.

This triggers visual studio to show the Reload project dialog. Can I execute a command that silences the prompt and reloads it anyway?

```
$csproj = [xml](Get-Content $project)

# ... do stuff here

$csproj.Save($project.FullName)

# a prompt comes up in VS, but I want to force a Reload of the project
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292577/how-can-i-reload-a-visual-studio-project-thru-a-nuget-powershell-script

Comment: This makes the prompt come up, but I want to force a reload instead.

Comment: @Marnix, please share were you able to find a way to force a reload without triggering a prompt?

Comment: I couldn't unfortunately. We managed to make a workaround by re-creating the whole install script in Powershell and not using the built-in visual studio console version. So we implemented all things that nuget.exe doesn't do in powershell.

Comment: Oh. Thank you for the answer, @Marnix!