# Insert Import into project file at position 0 and save without prompt using Nuget install.ps1

Tags: nuget, installation, visual-studio-2019, projects-and-solutions

I am building a Nuget package which has a tools folder with install.ps1. This Nuget package is dependent on NugetPowerTools package which provides some APIs to work with the project and its properties. I have pasted the code used in my install.ps1 below.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
$buildProject = Get-MSBuildProject
$import = $buildProject.Xml.AddImport("Custom.Targets")
$buildProject.Save()
```

I have 2 questions.

1. The AddImport appends the target at the end (i.e., after other Import lines). I need to have my Import as the first line (since I have some functionality in this targets file which needs to be executed before others). Is it possible to insert the Import at first (i.e., my import with Custom.Targets should be the first item of Import in the project file)? I can't find an Insert method.
2. Once the project file is modified by this install.ps1, there is a pop up /prompt in Visual Studio with 4 options namely, SaveAs, Discard, Overwrite and Ignore. I want to save & overwrite the project file without this prompt / pop up from my install.ps1. This is to avoid any accidental mistake by the user. To overcome, I found a link below, which has the following line of code, which helps me overcome this issue.

[How can I reload a visual studio project thru a nuget powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292577/how-can-i-reload-a-visual-studio-project-thru-a-nuget-powershell-script)

```
$(get-item $project.FullName).lastwritetime=get-date
```

But now, I get another pop up / prompt with options to Reload, Reload All, Ignore, Ignore All. Is there a way to Reload this project without this prompt?

Please help.

Note: I am OK not to use NugetPowerTools if someone can provide the correct syntax without NugetPowerTools also.

Comment: Hi Perry, Sorry for the delay. I can see something posted at https://www.nuget.org/packages/WiX.Toolset.UnofficialFork/#. When I look at the install.ps1 of this package, I can see some code similar to what I am looking for.

Comment: l think you have got your answer from the install.ps1 powershell script from the nuget. If you have any other issues, please feel free to let us know and we are glad to help you.

Comment: Sure Perry. Thanks a lot for the timely help.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to insert the Import at first (i.e., my import with
>   Custom.Targets should be the first item of Import in the project
>   file)? I can't find an Insert method.

Since you want to let `Custom.Targets` to be the first import project in the `xxx.proj` file, you can separate this from Powershell and then use [Custom Build Targets or Props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package) to realize it. Actually, l am not similar with powershell script, so l recommend this easy function which was released since **NuGet 2.5**.

**Note** that this function should use [nuget.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package) and [nuspec file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#the-role-and-structure-of-the-nuspec-file) to pack your project.

**Step 1)**

Create a file in a new folder called `build` which exists in the root directory of the project.And then put `<package_id>.props` file into it.Besides, you would better add an appropriate sub folder which is related to the framework. Like this:

```
\build
    \netstandard2.0
        \<package_id>.props
```

**Attention**: see this from the document:

***.props is added at the top of the project file; .targets is added at the bottom.***

`.targets` and`.props` files are of the same nature, but under this nuget mechanism,.props files are placed at the top of the `xxx.proj` file. Besides, the file name should be the same as the package_id which is defined in the nuspec file.

So you should change your `Custom.Targets` to `<package_id>.pros`.

**Step 2)**

Then in the .nuspec file, be sure to refer to these files in the  node:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
    <metadata minClientVersion="2.5">
    <!-- ... -->
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <!-- Include everything in \build -->
        <file src="build\**" target="build" />

        <!-- Other files -->
        <!-- ... -->
    </files>
</package>
```

**Step 3)**

Finally, use the **nuget.exe** to pack your project.

**In addition**, please make sure that the properties, items or targets which you use are defined in your custom props in case when you use some common properties which are defined in the `Microsoft.Common.props` or `Microsoft.CSharp.targets`,they cannot be found and report errors because these files are imported after your custom props.

This is the result which l have tested:

[image]

> But now, I get another pop up / prompt with options to Reload, Reload
>   All, Ignore, Ignore All. Is there a way to Reload this project without
>   this prompt?

I think this behavior is controlled by VS itself rather than powershell. VS will detect the status of these files and pop up a prompt. So this is controlled by the VS SDK. Or I guess you can refer to [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783648/is-there-a-setting-in-vs-2010-that-will-allow-it-to-recover-open-files-after-a-p) to override the behavior of VS via the VS SDK interface.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Hi Perry, Thanks a lot for your detailed reply. However, I probably forgot to mention that mine is a WiX project in Visual Studio. So, the folders like .net standard 2.0 is not relevant. Also, it is not at all an SDK project. Hence I am not sure if I can use the .props approach. Also, I normally use the Nuget Package Explorer to build my Nuget packages. Considering all these, will the steps outlined by you, work for me? Anyways, thanks a lot once again for the detailed explanation.

Comment: the folders like .net standard 2.0 is not the necessary format, you can just put the props into the build folder. The props file is the same as the targets file.It can contains lots of target, properties and so on. ·Nuget Package Explorer` is similar to `nuget.exe cli` and it can also pack wix projects. You can just follow the [guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package) to get what you want.